# Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'broadcast_news_images/13331558akantony2.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in

Tags: php

Script shows this msg when uploading a image.Please help

Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'broadcast_news_images/13331558akantony2.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in D:\inetpub\vhosts\gallinews.com\httpdocs\adminpanel\imgcrop.php on line 19

```
Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Permission denied in D:\inetpub\vhosts\gallinews.com\httpdocs\adminpanel\imgcrop.php on line 19
```

//This is imgcrop.php file

```
<?php
    class SimpleImage 
    {
        var $image; var $image_type;
        function load($filename)
         {   
        $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
         $this->image_type = $image_info[2]; 
         if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) 
         {   
         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
          }
           elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) 
           {   
           $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename); 
           } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG )
            {   $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename); } }

        function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {   if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) { imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression); } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {   imagegif($this->image,$filename); } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {   imagepng($this->image,$filename); } if( $permissions != null) {   chmod($filename,$permissions); } }  //Line number 19 error

        function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) 
        {   
            if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) 
            { 
                imagejpeg($this->image); 
            } 
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) 
            {   
                imagegif($this->image); 
            } 
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) 
            {   
                imagepng($this->image); 
            } 
        } 

        function getWidth() 
        {   
            return imagesx($this->image); 
        }

        function getHeight() 
        {   
            return imagesy($this->image); 
        }

        function resizeToHeight($height) 
        {   
            $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight(); $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio; $this->resize($width,$height); 
        } 


        function resizeToWidth($width) 
        { 
            $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth(); 
            $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio; 
            $this->resize($width,$height); 
        }   

        function scale($scale) 
        { 
            $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100; 
            $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100; 
            $this->resize($width,$height); 
        }   

        function resize($width,$height) 
        { 
            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
            imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight()); 
            $this->image = $new_image; 
        }   
    } 
//  include('SimpleImage.php');
?>




This is the file where i use imgcrop file.

<?php 

include 'connect.php';
include 'unset_user.php';
?>
<?php
include('imgcrop.php');
$errflag=false;

if(isset($_POST['edit_broadcast_news']))
{
        function clean($str)
    {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
                $str = stripslashes($str);
            }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }


    if(isset($_POST['bdn_id']) && $_POST['bdn_id']!='') 
    {
        $bdn_id=clean($_POST['bdn_id']);

    }

    if(isset($_POST['bdn_title']) && $_POST['bdn_title']!='')   
    {
        $bdn_title=clean($_POST['bdn_title']);

    }
    else
    {
        $errflag=true;
        $broadcast_news_edit_err[]="Please Enter News Title";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['bdn_desc']) && $_POST['bdn_desc']!='') 
    {
        $bdn_desc=clean($_POST['bdn_desc']);

    }
    else
    {
        $errflag=true;
        $broadcast_news_edit_err[]="Please Enter News Description";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['full_image']) && $_POST['full_image']!='') 
    {
        $full_image=clean($_POST['full_image']);
    }

        if(isset($_POST['b_news']) && $_POST['b_news']!='') 
    {
        $b_news=clean($_POST['b_news']);

    }
    if(isset($_POST['bdn_status']) && $_POST['bdn_status']!='') 
    {
        $bdn_status=clean($_POST['bdn_status']);

    }
    else
    {
        $errflag=true;
        $broadcast_news_edit_err[]="Please Select Status ";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['obdn_image']) && $_POST['obdn_image']!='') 
    {
        $obdn_image=clean($_POST['obdn_image']);

    }


    if(empty($_FILES['bdn_image']['name']))
        {

        }
        else
        {   
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["bdn_image"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
            if ((($_FILES["bdn_image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["bdn_image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["bdn_image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["bdn_image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["bdn_image"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["bdn_image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            /*&& ($_FILES["bdn_image"]["size"] < 1000000)*/
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
              {

                  if ($_FILES["bdn_image"]["error"] > 0)
                    {
                    $prod_add_err[]=$_FILES["bdn_image"]["error"] . "<br>";
                    $errflag=true;

                    }
                  else
                    {




                    }
              }
            else
              {

              }
        }

    if($errflag==true)
    {
        $_SESSION['broadcast_news_edit_err']=$broadcast_news_edit_err;
            //header("location:edit_broadcast_news.php?bdn_id=$bdn_id");
        print_r($broadcast_news_edit_err);  
    }
    else
    {
                $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['bdn_image']['tmp_name'];



                  if ($tmpFilePath != "")
                  {

                    $imgname=rand(0000,9999).$_FILES["bdn_image"]["name"];





                $image = new SimpleImage();    
                $image->load($tmpFilePath);
                $image->resize(1024,768);
                $image->save('broadcast_news_images/'.$imgname); 

                  }
                  else
                  {
                        $imgname=$obdn_image;  
                        echo "2";
                  }
        //,bdn_date=curdate()
        //g_id, g_name, g_position, g_status, g_flag
        $add_bd=mysql_query("update broadcast_news set bdn_title='$bdn_title', bdn_desc='$bdn_desc', bdn_image='$imgname',full_img_disp='$full_image', bdn_status='$bdn_status' where bdn_id='$bdn_id'");
        if($add_bd)
        {
            if($imgname==$obdn_image)
            {

            }
            else
            {
            @unlink('broadcast_news_images/'.$obdn_image.'');   
            }
            echo 123;
            $_SESSION['broadcast_news_edit_success']="Broadcast News Edited Successfully";
            //header("location:edit_broadcast_news.php?bdn_id=$bdn_id");
            //exit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo 32;
            unlink('broadcast_news_images/'.$imgname.'');   
            $_SESSION['broadcast_news_edit_err']="Broadcast News Not Edited.Please Try Again";
            //header("location:edit_broadcast_news.php?bdn_id=$bdn_id");
            //exit();
        }

    }
}
else
{
echo "df";  
}
?>
```

Comment: File that you have given in the function, does not have permission check the permission and give the writing permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 
'broadcast_news_images/13331558akantony2.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in 
D:\inetpub\vhosts\gallinews.com\httpdocs\adminpanel\imgcrop.php on line 19
```

The directory where you are trying to write your images (broadcast_news_images/) need writing permissions for the http user